# AX210 with jammy - wifi stopped working

Tags: wireless

just installed an AX210 card on my Lenovo and right after installing it was working.

Second boot after an upgrade wifi stopped working.

Tried deleting usr `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` but still no improvements.

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
```

prompts nothing.

Is there anything missing?

Tried reinstalling Linux-firmware just in case but didn't help either.

I have 5.15.0-43 backport-iwlwifi/9858

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bad contact. Does it show in `lspci`?

Comment: showing some errors `sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @abu_bua at the minute it shows pretty much the same info/errors as the dmesg | grep iwl I posted in the following answer, but this is happening now only after disabling secure mode boot. Before, it wouldn't even try loading any module.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working since I disabled secure boot.

I also downloaded iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode and iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode from git, but just found out I did it from within my home dir so I assume it was useless.

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
    [    3.730430] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    3.730431] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    3.841509] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.855129] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.855235] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.856927] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.856953] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    3.857425] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.937406] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.109993] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded PNVM version 05a8dfca
[    4.121541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    4.191895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: c4:bd:e5:1b:cb:dc
[    4.210729] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```